# I want to build a Virtual Machine, are there any good references?

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine-languages

I'm looking to build a Virtual Machine as a platform independent way to run some game code (essentially scripting).

The Virtual Machines that I'm aware of in games are rather old: Infocom's [Z-Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-machine), LucasArts' [SCUMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCUMM), id Software's [Quake 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_3). As a .net Developer, I'm familiar with the [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and looked into the [CIL Instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) to get an overview of what you actually implement on a VM Level (vs. the language level). I've also dabbled a bit in [6502 Assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6502) during the last year.

The thing is, now that I want¹ to implement one, I need to dig a bit deeper. I know that there are stack based and register based VMs, but I don't really know which one is better at what and if there are more or hybrid approaches. I need to deal with memory management, decide which low level types are part of the VM and need to understand *why* stuff like [ldstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx) works the way it does.

My only reference book (apart from the Z-Machine stuff) is the [CLI Annotated Standard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321154932), but I wonder if there is a better, more general/fundamental lecture for VMs? Basically something like the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), but for VMs? I'm aware of Donald Knuth's [Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) which uses a register-based VM, but I'm not sure how applicable that series still is, especially since it's still unfinished?

Clarification: The goal is to build a specialized VM. For example, Infocom's Z-Machine contains OpCodes for setting the Background Color or playing a sound. So I need to figure out how much goes into the VM as OpCodes vs. the compiler that takes a script (language TBD) and generates the bytecode from it, but for that I need to understand what I'm really doing.

---

¹ I know, modern technology would allow me to just interpret a high level scripting language on the fly. But where is the fun in that? :) It's also a bit hard to google because Virtual Machines is nowadays often associated with VMWare-type OS Virtualization...

Comment: note that for a stack based machine to be turing-complete it *needs* memory outside the stack otherwise it is just a [PDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)

Comment: The first question is: how far do you want to go? I never looked at SCUMM/SCUMMVM but assume that's quite high level knowing about graphical things moving around etc. whereas CIL is ... so you have to define your memory model (stackbased register based, mixture, mess, ..) and opcodes (i.e. assembler instructions) and then a first version of a VM is a loop `do { switch(opcode) {case OP1: ... case OP2: ...} while (nextop);` then maybe a compiler ... and then the fun starts - optimization to make it actually work

Comment: Try starting with implementing a simple Forth runtime.

Comment: How exactly is `Quake 3` a virtual machine?

Comment: @Ramhound the id tech engines have long used some form of internal virtualisation, [this article](http://fabiensanglard.net/quake3/qvm.php), or [Wikipedia's info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_3#Virtual_machine) might explain better.

Comment: @johannes Indeed, the OpCodes in e.g. Infocom's Z-Machine include things like `Set foreground color` on top of a whole bunch of low level math stuff. That what I'm trying to learn though, how much goes into the VM vs. the Compiler that compiles high level code into the bytecode the VM needs.

Comment: set foreground can still be quite low level ... a game-specific highlevel VM might have operations like "move player character in some direction" and then the VM itself decides about all consequences to graphics and other aspects ... so in my opinion you should look at different instruction sets first and decide where you want to go ... defining the degree of abstraction is the tough thing ...

Comment: As reference: here the OpCodes for PHP's Zend Engine: http://php.net/internals2.opcodes

Comment: @MichaelStum: I think you should find some interesting problem to solve utilizing your VM. That will give you a lot of direction in what needs to be in your VM. You could try making a virtual PIC or Arduino or something.

Comment: Anton Ertl has done some related research: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/projects/interpreters.html

Comment: I would start with a very low-level, orthogonal instruction set, and try to build on from that.  If certain operations prove repetitious and slow, you can extend the virtual machine to have an optimized path for that specific operation.  Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 19):

I'd start by checking [Lua](http://lua.org).  Both as a sample implementation, and as a very usable VM/language out of the box if you finally decide not to roll your own.

The source code is very readble, and there's also the [Annotated source code](http://stevedonovan.github.com/lua-5.1.4/).  And some [Design documents](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) written by the main author, Roberto Ierusalimschy.

Finally, if you choose to use it instead of your own, you'll find that it's been long a favorite among game developers, and there's a *very* high performance [JIT implementation](http://luajit.org/luajit.html).

About stack- vs register-based, I think stack-based VMs are easier to design, but the compiler can be more complex.  As the Iesualimschy paper notes, Lua was one of the first register-based language VMs, but afterwards several others have sprouted, Most notably, LLVM, Dalvik, and some modern JavaScript VMs.

Comment: About stack vs register machines: I remember a quote from Parrot/Perl6 devs: "building a register based machine is harder, but we benefit from tons of existing research for our compiler side" (not literal)

Comment: +1 Lua has an excellent bytecode implementation and a very clean design for learning about VMs from.  In addition, you'll find that many people have customized Lua for their own needs, showing it to be quite extensible if you don't want to start from scratch.

Comment: Still going through this. Another great document from the developer about the VM: http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/talks/lua-ll3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any specific resources to link you to at the moment, but I've researched a similar topic in the past and found the **Smalltalk** VM to be a good learning aid as well.  There are many academic papers and articles written about the byte codes used by Smalltalk, as well as writing interpreters and VMs to use that bytecode.  A Google search for `smalltalk vm implementation` or `smalltalk bytecode interpreter` should yield lots of reading material.

If you'd like to see some source code or try out an implementation I recommend either the Squeak or Pharo versions.

The related language/VM **Self** might also interest you, as Self is basically Smalltalk with prototype-based objects (similar to JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I would start from analyzing of how [script] source code gets into your machine or runtime environment.

If you have something like in HTML documents `<a onclick="dosomething();">` then you will need very fast compiler, bytecode execution speed does not really matter that much in this case.
If your use cases are closer to Java/.NET where you can afford full blown compilation then VM architecture and bytecode structure will be closer Java bytecodes or IL.

Another criteria is what I name as "glueness". Originally scripts were developed as glue languages - scripts just define the way of how to connect various native functions together (Perl, Python, Ruby, JS). In that case effectiveness of VM and bytecode is far less critical than in case of Java/.NET when most of your code are functions written in the language itself.

And the last major criteria I would use is extensibility of your language. 
If you have plans to add to you language runtime many native objects/functions implemented in, say, C++ then your VM architecture should be "convenient" for integration with C++.
For example: if you plan to expose to script  C++ objects as they are then the only option for you will be reference counting as a heap management (like Python, see boost::python as an example of integration). If you plan to use moving/compacting heap/GC then it will be different story. Lua's way of adding native stuff into runtime is a bit tricky [for C++ developers].

In other words, try to define first your typical use case and it will be easier to suggest what to read for you.

Comment: Modern JavaScript compilers are quite complex, and well the question there is alwazs how much optimisation of the generated code you put in.

Comment: Javascript execution performance matters. Not for tiny scripts, but for larger JS-heavy sites, which for better or worse make up a significant portion of the more popular sites. There's a reason JS engines use JIT compilers (V8 doesn't even *have* an interpreter, it goes straight to machine code).

Comment: @delnan : JS use case is quite different from, say, Python. 
In Python when you need something like ray-tracing algorithm implementation you will do native library and call it from script.  This always be faster (or at least not slower) than any JIT solution. In JS realm you do not have such luxury as native code so the only option for you is to try to make your JS VM as fast as possible. But again, with the price. Evaluation of "dosomethingnative()" in HTML "<button onclick="dosomethingnative()"> in simple interpreter can be in orders of magnitude faster than in V8.

Comment: @c-smile My point exactly.

Comment: @delnan: but my point is quite different: analyse common use cases and only then you can decide what kind of architecture of VM, language syntax, etc. you will need.